# Falta la traducción de los consejos para novatos

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

Iba a postear mi primera respuesta y he visto que falta por traducir el texto de sugerencias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que hay actualmente:

> ## Tu Respuesta
>
> Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow en español!
>
> - Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your research!
>
> But avoid …
>
> - Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers.
> - Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience.
>
> To learn more, see our tips on writing great answers.

Propuesta (no soy linguista!)

> ## Tu Respuesta
>
> ¡Gracias por contribuir a una respuesta de StackOverflow en español!
>
> - Por favor asegúrate de responder a la pregunta. ¡Proporciona información y comparte tu investigación!
>
> Pero evita…
>
> - Pedir ayuda, aclaración, o responder a otras respuestas.
> - Si haces declaraciones basadas en opiniones asegúrate de respaldarlas con referencias o tu propia experiencia personal.
>
> Para obtener más información, consulta nuestros [consejos sobre cómo escribir grandes respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Me parece genial la traducción. Hay unas pequeñas cosas a tener en cuenta..: `asegurate` --> `asegúrate`x2. `Proporciona`-->`¡Proporciona`. `respuestas .`-->`respuestas.`. `própia`-->`propia`. `información ,`-->`información,`

Comment: @MiquelColl modifica la respuesta sin miedo, quizas asi podremos facilitar el trabajo a quien le toque hacer el cambio :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este es uno de esos casos raros en los que el texto no está en Transifex, sino directamente en nuestra base de datos, y por tanto no hay forma de que los traductores siquiera lo encuentren.

He cambiado el texto en inglés por la traducción de joc (con algún pequeño retoque) y de paso he traducido dos textos más que estaban en la misma situación: el aviso de "tu cuenta está a punto de ser bloqueada" y el mensaje *"Este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas para programadores"* que aparece a los usuarios nuevos.

Comment: Ya sale correctamente, muchas gracias!! `:)`